# Intra-process communication WinRT (messages replacement)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, ipc

I'm working on WinRT port from Win32, but I have a problem with threads and messages (vc++11). I can use is only thread pool or **std::thread** in WinRT ... so I implemented **std::thread**, it seems it's  working, but how can I communicate between threads? Is there some alternative (like **PostMessage()**, etc.)? In Android port we can use pipe, but nothing of this is in winrt :(

Thank you

Comment: You are mixing up the concepts of thread and process.  A pipe is only needed for inter **process** communication, not permitted in WinRT.  Threads only need a thread-safe queue.

Comment: @HansPassant: Not really. `PostMessage()` is used for both. And thread-safe queue is not sufficient, you still need something to notify the thread (but than it _is_ the answer, of course).

Comment: PostMessage() is just a way to use a thread-safe queue. The Windows message queue.  Rather restricted and above all, not available in WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

[std::conditional_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) with [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and plain only [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) should do the trick.